# Keydown event on Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

On this amazing editor ([Ace: Code Editor](http://ace.c9.io/)), there's a method which I can get the `on change` event, is there a `on keydown` event? Or a hack I can simulate it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no keydown event, you can add keydown event listener on textarea returned by `editor.textInput.getElement()`, but the better way is to use `editor.commands.addCommand`

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "...",
    exec: function() {},
    bindKey: {mac: "cmd-f", win: "ctrl-f"}
})
```

or `editor.keyBinding.addKeyboardHandler`

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using the text element returned by the editor... thanks for that.

Comment: using editor.textInput.getElement() seems pretty easy and works well.

Comment: "better" depends on what you need to do - if you want to add a command then addCommand is better, if you want a keydown event it is not

Answer (score 1):

I can't find it in [the documentation](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor), but in [this discussion](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2687#issuecomment-145392067), I found out about the `editor.commands.on('afterExec', ...)` API:

```js
editor.commands.on('afterExec', eventData => {
    if (eventData.command.name === 'insertstring') {
        console.log('User typed a character: ' + eventData.args);
    }
});
```

`afterExec` fires on every *command* in the editor. *Commands* include actions like typed text, appearance of completion popups on *ctrl+space*, etc...

It's not a direct analog of keydown event, but it is the thing I was googling for when I came here, so hopefully you'll find it useful.